# Eclipse Juno Install Dependencies (Offline Solution)

Tags: android, eclipse

Good day guys
I have this kind of problem from my Eclipes Juno
I can't create a new android project because of this one

[image: Install Dependencies]

and i found several topics about this problem
but almost of the answers was pointing into two solutions

"Uninstall the support library from the Android SDK manager"
"have an internet connection and update online"

and i have two problems too...
first, i don't have internet connection in our home
Second, "i don't have it" (Support Library)
This is my android SDK

[image: My Android SDK]

as you can see I have no Support Library so notting to uninstall

maybe you'll be confused "where did i get that platforms if as i said i have no internet connection in our home"
well i've manually downloaded all of it and manually extracted to my "plaform" directory....
i have encountered some errors before like this one

[image: SDK platform tools component is missing!]

and luckly i was able to solve it using just manual downloading and extracting (a little workarounds)
but this one seems to be one of the hardest to me for now...
I keep browsing the web for finding such a "support library.zip" so that all i have to do is extract that one to its respective directory
and a step by step to where do i extract it... but sadly i found nothing...

i im thinking of some posible solutions
and maybe i need a help of a person who has a good running Eclipse Juno
make a request like " can you zip your support library folder from your SDK and upload it here"
and a simple "path" to what directory do i have to extract it.

whatever it maybe...
ill just trying every single workarounds just to solve it "offline"
i know online solution is less hassle and just a little clicks and problem solved,
but did you know how it happened?
do you know what eclipse or SDK did to solve that?
that's the reason why i want it offline just for me to understand every bit of it...
i want to solve it Offline...

Thank you in advance.....

Answer (score 2):

you can go to download **ADT-20.0.0.zip** ,Install it and then restart Eclipse.
because Google is 2.2 and the earlier version to official library, support many 3.0 and higher version of the function, in the new construction time, the default will give you add libs folders and android - support - v4. Jar。
I also can be directly sent to you **ADT-20.0.0.zip**。please tell me your E-mail！

Comment: hmm...i've already installed  ADT 20.0.3 using manualy also
do i have to uninstall it?...
here is my email
nyu00001@yahoo.com